# Move element X when element Y is hovered on?

Tags: html, css, hover, position, css-position

```css
a img {
  width:3%;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}

a {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #090909;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">View <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/internet-28/48/31-512.png"> </a>
```

How can I make the image (the arrow) go `5px` to the right so `margin-left: 15px;` when the parent tag `<a>` is been hovered on? Is this possible without javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try this code

```css
a img {
  width:3%;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:10px;
  transition:0.5s;
}
a {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #090909;
}
a:hover img{
   opacity: 1; 
 margin-left: 50px;  
 transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(177deg);   
 zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">View <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/internet-28/48/31-512.png"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
a img {
  width:3%;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}

a:hover img {
  margin-left:15px;
}


a {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #090909;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">View <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/internet-28/48/31-512.png"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
a img {
  width:3%;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:10px;
  transition:0.5s;
}
a {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #090909;
}
a:hover img{
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">View <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/internet-28/48/31-512.png"> </a>
```